# Get selected value from embedded Unity3D web player to ASP.net web page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, unity-game-engine

I need to sync embedded unity3D app with asp.net web page. As an example when i click a button in unity3d embedded app, then my ASP.Net page should be able to read the returned value from unity3d web player (need to display the details of selected 3d model inside ASP.net page using ajax or what ever without reload the page). I dont have an idea whether it is possible to do. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can call JavaScript functions from inside your game:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
function MyFunction( arg ) {
    alert( arg );
}
-->
</script>
```

and inside Unity:

```
Application.ExternalCall( "MyFunction", myArgument );
```

You can also communicate in the other direction as well, but that is another question.